# Downvoting some other answer because one answer was downvoted

Tags: discussion, downvotes, ethics

I answered a question recently [Replace occurrences of NSString with `'` to `\'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798925/replace-occurrences-of-nsstring-with-to/29799136#29799136).

In the comments of the accepted answer one guy is saying that he downvoted the accepted answer only because another answer which is similar to the accepted answer was written first and downvoted and so he was doing justice by downvoting the accepted answer.

Isn't this kind of a misuse of a downvote?

Comment: Yes and no. Morally it may be wrong, but there are no justifications required whatsoever for down votes, people can cast them any way they like.

Comment: What a mess. People asking for *and* complaining about votes here and there (also among the deleted comments). But you know what would have been a much easier and more reasonable justification for a downvote on the accepted answer? "It's a code-block-only answer." Regardless of whose answer came first or whose was accepted - your answer is much more informative and well-written. If you had to pick one answer to represent the kind of quality Stack Overflow is known for, which would you choose?

Comment: Ughghgh [not again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813878/invalid-update-invalid-number-of-rows-in-section/29814184#comment47756025_29814184).

Comment: Personally, I'd like to see a required comment for a downvote, explaining the reason for the downvote.  That would remove a lot of inadvertent (which I've done) and malicious (as in Apoorv's example) downvotes from occurring in the first place.

Comment: @BobStout There is no chance of that happening. We probably get a dozen requests per week on Meta for it, it has been discussed since forever. Having to comment when you down vote will be a PITA and lead to retribution (because you will know who downvoted). No system is perfect but the current one works pretty well.